# errors with structure save and load function

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct birdhome{
  int area;
  int heightcm;
  int feederquantity;
  char hasNest[6];
};
struct bird{
  char isRinged[6];
  char nameSpecies[50];
  int birdAgeMonths;
  struct BirdHome *hom;
  char gender[7];
};

int save(char * filename, struct bird *st, int n);
int load(char * filename);

int main(void)
{
    char * filename = "birds.dat";
    struct bird birds[] = { "True","sparrow",3,10,20,2,"False","Male","False","crane",24,50,100,6,"True","Female","False","False","griffin",10,100,80,1,"False","Male" };
    int n = sizeof(struct bird) / sizeof(birds[0]);

    save(filename, birds, n);
    load(filename);
    return 0;
}

int save(char * filename, struct bird * st, int n)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;
    
    int size = n * sizeof(struct bird);

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return 1;
    }
   
    c = (char *)&n;
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        putc(*c++, fp);
    }
   
    c = (char *)st;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        putc(*c, fp);
        c++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int load(char * filename){
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;
    int m = sizeof(int);
    int n, i;

    
    int *pti = (int *)malloc(m);

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    
    c = (char *)pti;
    while (m>0)
    {
        i = getc(fp);
        if (i == EOF) break;
        *c = i;
        c++;
        m--;
    }
 
    n = *pti;

   
    struct bird * ptr = (struct bird *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct bird));
    c = (char *)ptr;
    
    while ((i= getc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        *c = i;
        c++;
    }
   
    printf("\n%d birds in the file stored\n\n", n);

    for (int k = 0; k<n; k++)
    {
        printf("%-10d %-6s %-50s %-24d %-100d %-100d %-10d %-10s %-10s  \n", k + 1, (ptr + k)->isRinged, (ptr + k)->nameSpecies,(ptr + k)->birdAgeMonths,(ptr + k)->hom.area,(ptr + k)->hom.heightcm,(ptr + k)->hom.feederquantity,(ptr + k)->hom.hasNest,(ptr + k)->gender);
    }
```

Well, the program is theoretically running. The problem is with the `printf` inside the `load` function.
The error says that all the structure types that come in `struct Birdhome` is a
pointer and that I should use `->` instead of `.` in it.

But when I do this it says that I should change the `.` to `->`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `fread()` and `fwrite()`?

Comment: `bir.hom` is a pointer. Saving a pointer to a file won't work, it won't save the data that the pointer points to.

Comment: You also can't initialize the structure that it points to in the initialization list of the `birds` array.

Comment: @PatrickZ `pti` is set in the `while (m>0)` loop.

Comment: Summing up the comments above, it would be much simpler to declare `bird.hom` directly as a struct instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `bird.hom` is a pointer. Saving a pointer to a file is not a useful thing to do, because memory addresses change from one process to another. It's also not saving the contents of the `BirdHome` structure. And your initialization of `birds` doesn't work, because you can't initialize members of an indirect structure as part of the main structure.

You should declare it as an embedded structure rather than a pointer.

```
struct bird{
  char isRinged[6];
  char nameSpecies[50];
  int birdAgeMonths;
  struct BirdHome hom;
  char gender[7];
};
```

Declaring it as a pointer would be useful if you wanted a dynamically-sized array of homes, or you wanted to allow multiple birds to reference the same `BirdHome` structure. If that's what you really need, you'll need to redesign your save and load functions so they dereference the pointer and save what it points to. And if you have a dynamically-sized array of `BirdHome`, you need to include the array size in `bird`.

Other errors in your code:

You have an extra `"False"` in the initialization list of `birds`. It should be:

```
struct bird birds[] = { "True","sparrow",3,10,20,2,"False","Male","False","crane",24,50,100,6,"True","Female","False","griffin",10,100,80,1,"False","Male" };
```

Your calculation of `n` is incorrect. It should be:

```
int n = sizeof(birds) / sizeof(birds[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i've tried to do what you've adviced, and thir helped. the program ran but it only prints and saves only one element of structure(only 1 bird). can you suggest something?

Comment: `int n = sizeof(struct bird) / sizeof(birds[0]);` should be `int n = sizeof(birds) / sizeof(birds[0]);`